# php code trying to echo json data

Tags: php, json

I have this output and i'am just trying to echo token or store token in a variable

```
object(stdClass)#1 (9) {
 ["loggedIn"]=> bool(true) 
["token"]=> string(32) "xe5b6bHPPo-_nAvB78NfTpopq9e44bYb" 
["secret"]=> string(20) "icCPoDvcf1Vvm2i7-6GM" 
["expirationTimestamp"]=> string(24) "2016-11-26T16:32:29.728Z" 
["type"]=> string(4) "USER" 
["data"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (17)}
```

here is my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://security.voluum.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic plFubTHhcl93MzA4QHJJkQ9vqmNvwTpMNYYUIz5kcm9s";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

var_dump(json_decode($result));
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));

echo $result->token;
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

is the code above correct? how can i extract a single data from the output? please help me

Comment: Your decoding in your vardump but not anywhere else? Put your decoded json into a variable then access it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$res_decoded = json_decode($result);
echo $res_decoded->token;
```

Comment: thanks, big help i have stumble into another problem ill try to solve this first then ask hel when i cant do it :D

Comment: hi i just have folluw-up question is it possible to echo it cleanly like having newline on every array or object its really hard to find the data its lump up together.